# How to use Jquery Id selection with Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

So I have a section in my script that looks like the following:

```
$('input[id="TestMyId"]').autocomplete({
    source: availableChoice
 },
});
```

This works great, I get my autocomplete to fire and I can select from a list of choices, but when I make Test a string variable and try to concatenate it with MyId I can not get it to fire at all:

```
@{
    var foo = "Test";
}
<body..../>
<script>
    $('input[id="' + @foo + 'MyId"]').autocomplete({
        source: availableChoice
     },
    });
</script>
```

foo is declared as a global variable in the .cshtml.  Not sure why the Id selection is not working when I concatenate the names? Any help would be appreciate it.

Ok I've posted below a bit more detail, Id is FirstNameId in this test case, trying to combine it with the @prefix variable:

```
    @using System.Collections.Concurrent
    @model MyModel

    @{
        var prefixt = "TestContactInformation";
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController"))
    {

    <article class="widget widgetFullPage" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" id="articlePrimaryContact" style="height:auto">
        <h2>Test Information</h2>

        <table id="tableContactInformation">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 180px; padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 15px;"><label>Relationship to Policyholder</label></td>
                <td style="width: 50px; padding-top: 15px">@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PrimaryContact.ContactRole, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.RelToPolicyList, new { id = @prefixt + "RoleId", style = "width:130px", tabindex = @tabIndexBase + 1 })</td>
                <td style="width: 100px; padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 15px;" id=" titlelable"><label>Title</label></td>
                <td style="width: 200px; padding-top: 20px;padding-left: 12px;" id="TitleText">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PrimaryContact.Title, null, new { id = @prefixt + "TitleId", style = "width:250px", tabindex = @tabIndexBase + 8 })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id=@prefixt>
                <td style="width: 150px; padding-left: 15px;"><label>Contact Description</label></td>
                <td style="width: 100px">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PrimaryContact.ContactRoleDescription, null, new { id = @prefixt + "DescriptionId", style = "width:250px", tabindex = @tabIndexBase + 2 })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 30px;">
                <td style="width: 100px; padding-left: 15px;">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    @if (@prefixt == "TestContactInformation")
                    {
                        <a id="LearnMore"><img src="~/Images/info.png" alt="" /></a>
                    }
                </td>
                @*<td style="width: 100px;">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PrimaryContact.FirstName, null, new { id = @prefixt + "FirstNameId", style = "width:250px", tabindex = @tabIndexBase + 3 })</td>*@
                <td style="width: 100px;">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PrimaryContact.FirstName, null, new { id = @prefixt + "FirstNameId", style = "width:250px", tabindex = @tabIndexBase + 3 })</td>
                <td style="width: 100px;padding-left: 15px;"><label>Address Line 1</label></td>
                <td style="width: 200px;padding-left: 12px;">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PrimaryContact.AddressLine1, null, new { id = @prefixt + "Address1Id", style = "width:250px", tabindex = @tabIndexBase + 9 })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 30px;">
                <td style="width: 100px;  padding-left: 15px;"><label>Last Name</label></td>
                <td style="width: 100px; ">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PrimaryContact.LastName, null, new { id = @prefixt + "LastNameId", style = "width:250px", tabindex = @tabIndexBase + 4 })</td>
                <td style="width: 100px;  padding-left: 15px;"><label>Address Line 2</label></td>
                <td style="width: 200px; padding-left: 12px;">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PrimaryContact.AddressLine2, null, new { id = @prefixt + "Address2Id", style = "width:250px", tabindex = @tabIndexBase + 10 })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 30px;">
                <td style="width: 100px;  padding-left: 15px;"><label>Email</label></td>
                <td style="width: 100px; ">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PrimaryContact.Email, null, new { id = @prefixt + "EmailId", style = "width:250px", tabindex = @tabIndexBase + 5 })</td>
                <td style="width: 100px;  padding-left: 15px;"><label>City</label></td>
                <td style="width: 200px; padding-left: 12px;">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PrimaryContact.City, null, new { id = @prefixt + "CityId", style = "width:250px", tabindex = @tabIndexBase + 11 })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 30px;">
                <td style="width: 100px;  padding-left: 15px;"><label>Phone</label></td>
                <td style="width: 100px; ">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PrimaryContact.Phone, null, new { id = @prefixt + "PhoneId", @class = "phone", style = "width:250px", tabindex = @tabIndexBase + 6 })</td>
                <td style="width: 100px; padding-left: 15px;"><label>State</label></td>
                <td style="width: 200px; padding-left: 12px;">@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PrimaryContact.State, Model.PrimaryContact.StatesList ?? (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.StatesList, new { id = @prefixt + "StateId", style = "width:130px", tabindex = @tabIndexBase + 12 })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 30px;">
                <td style="width: 100px;  padding-left: 15px; padding-bottom: 20px"><label>Ext.</label></td>
                <td style="width: 100px;padding-bottom: 20px">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PrimaryContact.Ext, null, new { id = @prefixt + "ExtId", style = "width:250px", @class = "numbersOnly", tabindex = @tabIndexBase + 7 })</td>
                <td style="width: 100px;  padding-left: 15px;padding-bottom: 20px"><label>Zip</label></td>
                <td style="width: 200px;padding-left: 12px;padding-bottom: 20px">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PrimaryContact.Zip, null, new { id = @prefixt + "ZipId", @class = "zip", style = "width:250px", tabindex = @tabIndexBase + 13 })</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </article>

    }

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" />
    <style>
        .ui-corner-all,
        .ui-corner-top,
        .ui-corner-left,
        .ui-corner-tl {
            border-top-left-radius: 0;
        }

        .ui-corner-all,
        .ui-corner-top,
        .ui-corner-right,
        .ui-corner-tr {
            border-top-right-radius: 0;
        }

        .ui-corner-all,
        .ui-corner-bottom,
        .ui-corner-left,
        .ui-corner-bl {
            border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
        }

        .ui-corner-all,
        .ui-corner-bottom,
        .ui-corner-right,
        .ui-corner-br {
            border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var availableContacts = [];

        @foreach (var theContact in Model.ContactsList)
        {
            @:availableContacts.push( {value: "@theContact.FirstName, @theContact.LastName, @theContact.City, @theContact.State", label: "@theContact.FirstName, @theContact.LastName" });
        }

        //$("input[id='TestContactInformationFirstNameId']").autocomplete({
        //    source: availableContacts,
        //    select: function (event, ui) {
        //        var firstName = ui.item.value.split(',')[0];
        //        var lastName = ui.item.value.split(',')[1];
        //        var city = ui.item.value.split(',')[2];
        //        var state = ui.item.value.split(',')[3];
        //        alert(firstName);
        //        alert(lastName);
        //        alert(city);
        //        alert(state);
        //    },
        //});

        var theConcated = @string.Format("{0}FirstNameId", @prefixt);
        $("input[id='" + theConcated + "']").autocomplete({
            source: availableContacts,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var firstName = ui.item.value.split(',')[0];
                var lastName = ui.item.value.split(',')[1];
                var city = ui.item.value.split(',')[2];
                var state = ui.item.value.split(',')[3];
                alert(firstName);
                alert(lastName);
                alert(city);
                alert(state);
            },
        });

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
```

The commented out section with

```
$("input id='TestContactInformationFirstNameId']")
```

works great, but running the other section with the combined string I get is this:

```
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'TestContactInformationFirstNameId' is undefined
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: You don't need at symbol

Comment: Do a console.log('input[id="' + @foo + 'MyId"]'); to see what Razor is generating

Comment: I get a invalid character error with that in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after many trials and errors found the following to be working for my case, posting here incase it's helpful to someone else:

```
$("input[id='@prefixt" + "FirstNameId']")
```

Or

```
$("#@prefixt" + "FirstNameId")
```

Both seems to work, looks like the variable call needs to be inside the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This selector is not performant in jQuery.  You should use the ID selector first and then apply the input constraint using the filter function (if is even necessary since ID are meant to be unique).

```
$('#' + @string.Format("'{0}'", foo) + 'MyId').filter('input');
```

If you are doing good things, meaning keeping the ID property unique per page, then the following should work.

```
$('#' + @string.Format("'{0}'", foo) + 'MyId').autocomplete({
    source: availableChoice
 });
```

Comment: just gave that a try,didn't seem to work, the Ids are definitely unique, as in both cases they would be the same "TestMyId". and also without the @ infront of foo I get the javascript error foo is undefined.

Comment: Try my edit. Modified to to apply formatting. I didn't know you were using Razor

Comment: getting syntax error with that... I think I'll have another look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Show me the error if you cant figure it out.  Im willing to help.

Comment: I've updated with some more code and the error I'm getting